# Susy gem: How to find out which version of Susy is installed?

Tags: susy-compass, susy

Does any one know how can I found which version of **Susy** is installed on my windows system?

For example you can write in the command line compass -v to find out which version of Compass is installed on your machine.
But susy -v doesnt work.

Is there any command to find out which version of Susy is installed?

Thanks

Comment: Nice, this is the question that I was going to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a way.

```
gem list
```

shows all installed gems including Susy. :-)

Comment: You can also add `susy` to the command to only see installed Susy gems. So that would be `gem list susy`.

Comment: @KyleShevlin you may need to update the answer and get some credits.